# How to load missing firmwares?

Tags: drivers, firmware

So I was working with ubuntu 22.04 LTS and decided to update the kernel. The upgrade completed too but while the process was being done I found this message:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/rtl_nic/rt18125b-2.fw for module r8169
```

I sort of like got 18 messages like them. Can anyone please help me how can I load all these missing firmwares ?

Comment: What do you mean by "decided to update the kernel"? Did you install an unsupported mainline kernel?

Comment: I used 'apt-get dist-upgrade' and from there I got redirected to upgrade the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you don't need this missing firmware.

You may need it only if you have some new specific hardware. If everything works in your system, there is nothing to worry about.

The message means that linux kernel is aware of some firmware that it can't find in `/lib/firmware`. But the firmware is hardware specific.
New firmware will be added to `linux-firmware` package and these messages will disappear.

If you have some time and these messages are disturbing you, you can clone

```
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

and copy missing firmware to `/lib/firmware`.

Answer (score 1):

Please do:

```
cd /usr/lib/firmware/rtl_nic
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_nic/rtl8125b-2.fw
```

Reboot.